# count IDs in one table, multiply by value in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a single query to get the count of individual IDs in one table, and then take each of the counts and multiply them by a field in another table to get distinct totals.  So for example, one table would have these records:

```
cat_id_FK     
---------
100
100
101
101
101
```

and another table these records:

```
 cat_id_PK  |  cat_amount
----------     ----------
100            500.00
101            100.00
```

I would want the result set to be:

```
cat_id_PK  |  total
---------     -------
100           1000.00
101            300.00
```

I would also like to include other column fields from the table containing the primary keys as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a simple join and SUM.

```
SELECT
  cat_id_pk, 
  sum(cat_amount)
FROM
  t1 inner join t2
  on t1.cat_id_FK = t2.cat_id_PK
GROUP BY   
  cat_id_pk
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe650/3)

The joining does the multiplication. You can see if you just do a [normal select](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe650/4) the result would be

```
+-----------+------------+
| CAT_ID_PK | CAT_AMOUNT |
+-----------+------------+
|       100 |        500 |
|       100 |        500 |
|       101 |        100 |
|       101 |        100 |
|       101 |        100 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: The question is confusing.. my answer isn't right, and after reading your answer, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Conrad Frix This did it, thank you!  I guess I need to understand better how GROUP BY works because I had previously tried the INNER JOIN (without the group by) and was only getting back one result.  After modifying it per your suggestion, it returns exactly what I want.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: @hyphen Just so you know the behavior you describe is particular to MySQL. See [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.cat_id_PK,
       count(*)*(select count(*)
                 from tab_2
                 where tab_2.fk=a.cat_id_PK)
from tab1 a
```